# Getting 404 on liferay guest page redirection

Tags: liferay

Getting 404 while redirecting to mydomain.com/web/guest/home

But if given mydomain.com/web/guest/ i am getting redirected properly. To be consistent across environments i want the redirection to mydomain.com/web/guest/home work properly.

I don't have any specific settings in my portal-ext.properties for auth.server.url

What could be the issue?

Regards,
Sankar

Comment: What redirection you mean? Where?

Comment: @user2823220 check the landing page in site settings .. if this is not existent another default is going to handle that (first page in site ).. if I remember correctly , this was the reason,  i was experiencing similar behavior .. curl-ing home  and getting 404 , while in the browser it was shadowed...somehow ...